# How to install packages to specific versions of Python?

Tags: mac, installation, terminal, python, packages

I have multiple versions of Python installed on my system (Mac) according to the VS Code interpreter selector:

- Python 2.7.1 64-bit in `usr/bin/python`
- Python 3.7.4 64-bit ('base': conda) in `anaconda3/bin/python`
- Python 3.7.4 64-bit in `Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3`
- Python 3.7.4 64-bit in `usr/local/bin/python3`

Today, I installed the 'Matplotlib' package by using the following command:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

Now, when I try to import `matplotlib.pyplot` into a `.py` document, I get this error message:

> unresolved import 'matplotlib'Python(unresolved-import')

However, when I switch the project interpreter to the above 'Python 3.7.4 64-bit ('base': conda)' – it works.

So my question is,
how do I install packages to specific version of Python on my system?

Answer (score 1):

You have to point to the right python installation. A common method is to use pip (where conda Is not installed) directly from python, here an example:

```bsh
/usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip install matplotlib
```

By this way, you are going to install `matplotlib` from `/usr/local/bin/python3`

#### EDIT

The cause of the problem, is that you are running the `py` file with a python environment different from the one that you have install the dependencies with.

You can antepone the `env` path in your py file using this line at the start of the script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

# Script

``
```